# Как javascript получает доступ к cmd из браузера?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd

Подцепил вирус от которого с трудом избавился. И суть в том что последние дни я ничего не скачивал и не открывал. Но зато было такое что при посещении некоторых сайтов антивирус кричал ахтунг.

Я больше в администрировании разбираюсь, не особо силен в js, тем не менее насколько знаю js не имеет доступа к командной строке. Да и nodejs вроде как не может своими модулями получить доступ к cmd или powershell.

Как же тогда так делают, что зашел я на сайт, а мне джава скриптом подгрузился и запустился исполняемый файл, который уже можно наблюдать в процессах?

Или раньше ещё на андроиде замечал, зашел на сайт, телефон начинает вибрировать, выскочил алерт что  срочно нажми кнопку "ок" чтобы что-то там устранить. Как только нажмешь оно само скачает и установит приложение. Не могу понять как js получает доступ к функциям ОС. Ведь для установки apk файла, нужно вручную тыкать "установить". Подскажите где можно почитать об этом?

Comment: В исходных кодах того сайта, который так делает

Comment: да понятное дело что в исходных кодах. я хочу почитать какими модулями ноды, или какими методами джаваскрипта? Я же говорю, насколько знаю, ни джава скрипт, ни нода, не может получить доступа к ОС.

Comment: Ответ всё тот же - модули и методы можно увидеть в исходных кодах того сайта, который так делает

Comment: я уже сайт не найду, история почищена

Comment: Ну тогда мы можем объявить всю историю выдумкой, потому что "легальных" способов провернуть это нету)

Comment: ну да) значит я первый человек в мире, которому на телефоне выскакивали алерты, когда вибрирует телефон и просит нажать кнопку.
А ещё, зря в антивирусах есть функции защиты от вредоносных сайтов, ведь судя с ваших слов, это выдумка)

Comment: Ну функция alert описана в любом учебнике по javascript. Только вот она всё равно не позволяет устанавливать приложения